# Twin prime distribution centering twice a semiprime

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization, probabilistic-number-theory

What is the conjectured distributional behavior of semiprimes $pq$ ($p$ and $q$ are primes) having the property $2pq+1$ and $2pq-1$ are primes?

Comment: Clearly one of $p,q$ must be $3$, so this just asks for density of primes such that $6p\pm 1$ are prime. Naive heuristic suggests that up there should be $\asymp\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}$ such primes up to some bound $x$